# How do you set CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER for building Assimp for iOS?

Tags: ios, cmake

When I try to build Assimp by running `build_ios.sh`, it tells me:

```
CMake Error: your C compiler: "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_C_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
```

What I need the path to be is:

```
/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/...
```

I've tried changing `DEVROOT` in `build_ios.sh` and `IPHONE_xxxx_TOOLCHAIN.cmake`, because that's what `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` etc seem to get generated from, but it still gives me the same errors.

Answer (score 86):

**Option 1:**

You can set CMake variables at command line like this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="/path/to/your/c/compiler/executable" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/path/to/your/cpp/compiler/executable" /path/to/directory/containing/CMakeLists.txt
```

See [this](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#opt:-Dvar:typevalue) to learn how to create a CMake cache entry.

---

**Option 2:**

In your shell script `build_ios.sh` you can set environment variables `CC` and `CXX` to point to your C and C++ compiler executable respectively, example:

```
export CC=/path/to/your/c/compiler/executable
export CXX=/path/to/your/cpp/compiler/executable
cmake /path/to/directory/containing/CMakeLists.txt
```

---

**Option 3:**

Edit the CMakeLists.txt file of "Assimp": Add these lines at the top (must be added before you use `project()` or `enable_language()` command)

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/path/to/your/c/compiler/executable")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/path/to/your/cpp/compiler/executable")
```

See [this](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:set) to learn how to use `set` command in CMake. Also [this](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) is a useful resource for understanding use of some of the common CMake variables.

---

**Here is the relevant entry from the official FAQ: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-different-compiler**

Comment: Can we use option 3 to use compiler options? Let's I have to set it to `arm-linux-gnueabli-gcc -mfloat-fpu=hard`. Is this posiible? It adds semicolons instead of spaces while execution

Comment: The cmake command misses an equal sign when assigning cmake variables: It should be like `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/path/to/your/c/compiler/executable" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/path/to/your/cpp/compiler/executable" /path/to/directory/containing/CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: In option #3, `cmake` ignores the 2 variables setting after `project()` command

Comment: Option 2: doesn't work at all, it's ignored

Comment: For Option 2, since I had a compiler error earlier, I had a cache that needed to be removed before changes to CC and CXX would take affect. I did this with `rm -rf CMakeCache.txt`.

Answer (score 13):

The cc and cxx is located inside `/Applications/Xcode.app`. This should find the right paths

```
export CXX=`xcrun -find c++`
export CC=`xcrun -find cc`
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTIONS

1. Sometimes the project is created before installing `g++`. So install `g++` first and then recreate your project. This worked for me.
2. Paste the following line in CMakeCache.txt:
   `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/c++`

Note the path to `g++` depends on OS. I have used my fedora path obtained using `which g++`