# Can not install boost + libstdc++ on Travis CI

Tags: c++, boost, travis-ci

I have a minimal project ([here is the link](https://github.com/JohannesLorenz/travis_test)) which does not integrate with Travis CI. My .travis.yml:

```
language: cpp
compiler:
  - clang++
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - boost-latest
    packages:
      - libboost1.55-all-dev
      - cmake
script: mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make VERBOSE=1 && cd ..
```

This did configure (boost was found), [but not compile](https://travis-ci.org/JohannesLorenz/travis_test/builds/77011743) (it complained about a missing `std::map<int, int>::emplace()`, so I guess I needed to install a new g++ in order to get the new std-libraries. So I added this to packages:

```
packages:
    - gcc-4.8
    - g++-4.8
```

However, for strange reasons, cmake now complains that [it was missing boost](https://travis-ci.org/JohannesLorenz/travis_test/builds/77012749). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: were you able to get this working? I'm facing a similar issue  - unable to find boost

Comment: @akashrajkn yep, see the answer below. also make sure to read all comments there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [mine](https://github.com/srouquette/kodama/blob/master/.travis.yml). Here are some errors I can see in your file:

- you want to compile with gcc, but you only have clang++ as a compiler (mentioned in the log)
- you need to specify where you get gcc from, that's the line with `- ubuntu-toolchain-r-test`
- you need to export CXX to select the new gcc and not the default one `- if [ "$CXX" = "g++" ]; then export CXX="g++-4.9"; fi`

I'm still trying to figure some stuff about [why I can't link boost](https://travis-ci.org/srouquette/kodama/builds/77960510), that's how I found your post  :)

I may need to compile it myself...

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested, however, it somehow still chooses gcc 4.6 (though the export command is being executed before): https://travis-ci.org/JohannesLorenz/travis_test. The CMake command simply does "SET( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++" )", so what is wrong?

Comment: did you try to not specify this env in CMakelist.txt? I guess CMake overwrite this env. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588855/how-do-you-set-cmake-c-compiler-and-cmake-cxx-compiler-for-building-assimp-for-i

Comment: That worked! Thanks! It's now up on https://github.com/JohannesLorenz/travis_test .