# Catkin/ROS C++ library link error (undefined reference)

Tags: c++, redis, cmake, ros, catkin

I'm trying to use the [CPP Redis](https://github.com/Cylix/cpp_redis) library in my ROS project. It seems to fail to link to the cpp-redis correctly, on the following code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "communication.h"
#include "ros/ros.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Initialize and get a handle
    ros::init(argc, argv, "team3");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    //directly from the example
    cpp_redis::redis_client client;
    client.connect("127.0.0.1", 6379, [](cpp_redis::redis_client&) {
        std::cout << "client disconnected (disconnection handler)" << std::endl;
    });

}
```

With the following error:

```
/home/wouter/Documents/Team3_Visitor_Goal/ros/src/team3/src/publisher.cpp:17: undefined reference to `cpp_redis::redis_client::connect(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, std::function<void (cpp_redis::redis_client&)> const&)'
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks as followed:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(team3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang")
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) #set correct version

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  naoqi_driver
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

## Declare a catkin package
catkin_package()

## Build talker and listener
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(pepper src/publisher.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pepper ${catkin_LIBRARIES} cpp_redis tacopie)
```

I am using the CLang compiler in combination with the build system of [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Introduction) which is called catkin.

So there are some odd things:

- It looks like it is linked correctly because if I remove the `cpp_redis` and `tacopie` out of the target_link_libraries I get a lot more undefined references and my IDE just recognizes everything.
- It seems to have problems with the parameters of methods, because if I call a method on `client` without any parameters for instance `client.commit()` then it just compiles and runs. The code I use for the redis library did I get from the examples they provide so I assume they are correct.

I have seriously no clue what is going wrong, it works fine if I try to use it in a project without `catkin`. I hope you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Setting compiler **after** `project()` call doesn't work, see [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22619145/3440745).

Comment: @Tsyvarev If I define my compiler before `project()`, the compilation of my CMakeLists.txt runs into an infinite loop..

Comment: Probably something wrong with your project. In any case `It seems to have problems with the parameters of methods, because if I call a method on client without any parameters for instance client.commit() then it just compiles and runs.` usually means that your library is compiled with **different c++ compiler** than your executable. Like the library is built with `g++`, but you use `clang++` for executable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your reply, I also think it has to do with the compiler. I now changed the compiler to G++ version 4.8.5, then my redis library compiles correctly but ROS doesn't link correctly (same weird undefined references). If I change the G++ version to 5, it is the other way around (ROS links correctly, cppredis not). Is there any solution for that?

Comment: `Is there any solution for that?` - Compile ROS and redis with the *same* compiler, and use this compiler for your project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I now compiled both with G++5, that worked. Thank you very much!