# Problems with directory delimiters turning into backslashes when running cmake

Tags: windows, makefile, build, cmake, mingw

How can I get CMake to either not complain about escape characters with Windows paths, or interpret them as being separated by forward slashes?

I've tried:

```
SET CC="C:/Game Dev/Tools/MingW-w64/x86_64-7.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"
SET CXX="C:/Game Dev/Tools/MingW-w64/x86_64-7.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"
```

I've also tried making the following alias:

```
Cmake="C:/Game Dev/Tools/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/bin/cmake.exe" -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCXX="C:/Game Dev/Tools/MingW-w64/x86_64-7.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/g++.exe" -DCC="C:/Game Dev/Tools/MingW-w64/x86_64-7.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe" $1 $2 $3
```

I've tried the above with and without quotes, with `//` or `////` instead of `\`, and setting the environment variables via the control panel.

Moreover, I made the alias `Cmake="C:/Game Dev/Tools/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/bin/cmake.exe" -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCXX=g++.exe -DCC=gcc.exe $1 $2 $3` (since the MinGW bin path is on the environment variable path) as well, but to no avail.

```
X:\Scrolls2 (master)
λ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"
 -- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
 -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0 CMake Error at CMakeFiles/3.10.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake:1 (set):   Syntax error in cmake code at

     X:/Scrolls2/CMakeFiles/3.10.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake:1

   when parsing string

     C:\Game Dev\Tools\MingW-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin\g++.exe

   Invalid character escape '\G'. Call Stack (most recent call first): 
 CMakeLists.txt:10 (project)
```

I'm using Windows 10, and the latest versions of both MingW and CMake.

I get the same message regardless of whether I try to run it in cmder or cmd.

Comment: Not on windows, but maybe you could try to set the desired compilers (your 1st attempt) with the [`file(TO_CMAKE_PATH)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/file.html) and/or play with the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` option (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588855/how-do-you-set-cmake-c-compiler-and-cmake-cxx-compiler-for-building-assimp-for-i) SO Q&A)

Comment: From which shell are you running the `cmake` command? If it's `cmd.exe` the your `-D` parameters the you need to use backslashes and full paths and the add `:FILEPATH` like `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Game Dev\Tools\MingW-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin\g++.exe`. CMake will then translate the path correctly.

Comment: @Florian I'm using Cmd via Cmder. I aliased "Cmake="C:/Game Dev/Tools/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/bin/cmake.exe" -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Game Dev\Tools\MingW-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -DCMAKE_CCC_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Game Dev\Tools\MingW-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe $1 $2 $3". But when I run Cmake it says: CMake Error: The source directory "X:/Scrolls/Dev/Tools/MingW-w64/x86_64-7.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Comment: One thing that's probably worth elaborating on is that X:\ itself isn't a separate drive, but rather a psubst (persistent subst) of a a folder in my user folder (C:\Users\MyNameHere\Code).  @Florian

Comment: Much obliged for the editing and suggestion. I'll give it a shot now.  @compor

Comment: Adding quotes to each file path resolved finding them (the space in "Game Dev" messed it up on the first attempt before), but now it complains about the compiler failing to compile a test program: https://pastebin.com/eZCCMaFc @florian

Comment: I used to use CygWin before, and then both Cmake and GCC worked without problems. But then I need more recent versions (for C++17) plus SFML told me to use MinGW to compile it so I uninstalled CygWin and downloaded the latest versions of Cmake and MinGW.... and now I'm at a loss.

Comment: Just a hint: It is actually `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`, not `CMAKE_CCC_COMPILER`. And the reason why it failed to compile a simple test program is to be found in `X:/RPGUI/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log`. Just a guess: are you sure you have `mingw32-make` also installed? See also [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/howto_install_the_mingw_gcc_compiler_suite).