# cmake uses wrong version of compiler

Tags: cmake, ninja, rad-studio

I work with cmake and ninja in Windows 7. It worked flawless, till i opend an older version of my IDE. Now cmake uses the wrong compiler. Instead of 
C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Studio/19.0/bin/bcc32x.exe it now tries to use C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/RAD Studio/9.0/bin/bcc32x.exe.
Of course I read similar Questions here on stackoverflow and tried the solutions described there, but nothing seems to work ([How do you set CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER for building Assimp for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588855/how-do-you-set-cmake-c-compiler-and-cmake-cxx-compiler-for-building-assimp-for-i) for example). Even reinstallation of cmake does nothing. My windows environment variables are ok.

When i try to set CMake variables at command line like this:

```
cmake -G Ninja -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:\\Program Files     
(x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\19.0\\bin\\bcc32x.exe" -D   
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\19.0 
\\bin\\bcc32x.exe"
```

cmd Output was

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\cld>cd c:\

c:\>cmake -G Ninja -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:\\Program Files     
(x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\19.0\\bin\\bcc32x.exe" -D   
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\19.0 
\\bin\\bcc32x.exe"

C:\Users\cld\Desktop\smallCmakeTest
-- The C compiler identification is Embarcadero 7.30.36015
-- The CXX compiler identification is Embarcadero 7.30.36015
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/RAD  
Studio/9.0/bin/bcc32x.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/RAD  
Studio/9.0/bin/bcc32x.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules 
/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/RAD Studio/9.0/bin/bcc32x.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

     Change Dir: C:/Users/cld/Desktop/smallCmakeTest/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"C:/ninja/ninja.exe" "cmTC_c1b2f"
    [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_c1b2f.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_c1b2f.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\bcc32x.exe"    
-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\include\windows\crtl"
-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\
include\windows\sdk" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0  
\include\windows\rtl" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0  
\include\dinkumware64" -tM  -O0 -v -oCMakeFiles\cmTC_
c1b2f.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c testCCompiler.c
    CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/RAD Studio/9.0/bin/bcc32x.exe

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full   
path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


 CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

      should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be    
     lower
      if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For   
more
      information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
     This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

     -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/cld/Desktop/smallCmakeTest/CMakeFiles  
/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/cld/Desktop/smallCmakeTest/CMakeFiles
/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: From https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-different-compiler you can see hot to set a new compiler using command set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "path/new_compiler")

Comment: Absence of `cmake_minimum_required` could be a reason of almost any problem - most features comes after specific CMake versions, so they are disabled without the version.

Comment: Thank you. Tried to set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "path/new_compiler") . I set this line on the top of a minimum CMakeLists example. It still uses the wrong compiler.