# How to create minimal libfuzzer cmake example?

Tags: c, cmake, libfuzzer

I have a simple example of libFuzzer usage.

```
// Test_fuzzer.cc
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size) {
  if (size > 0 && data[0] == 'H')
    if (size > 1 && data[1] == 'I')
       if (size > 2 && data[2] == '!')
       __builtin_trap();
  return 0;
}
```

I am able to compile it with clang and run.

```
clang -g -O1 -fsanitize=fuzzer test_fuzzer.cc //OK
```

Now I want to add cmake to this example.

```
// CMakeLists.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.11)
project (Tutorial)

set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g -O1 -fsanitize=fuzzer")
add_executable(Tutorial test_fuzzer.cc)
```

```
cmake . //OK
make
```

But I get an error. How to fix it?

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: 
in function `_start': //why gcc, how to force cmake to use clang ????
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

make VERBOSE=1 results

```
[root@8c80cf55eaa2 test_cmake]# make VERBOSE=1'
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable Tutorial
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Tutorial.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang     CMakeFiles/Tutorial.dir/test_fuzzer.cc.o  -o Tutorial 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Tutorial.dir/build.make:84: Tutorial] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/test_cmake'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/Tutorial.dir/all] Error 2
```

Comment: `set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)` (before `project()`)?

Comment: It doesn't help. Same error

Comment: did you remove cmake files and reconfigured? Try to [clean cmake files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680420/looking-for-a-cmake-clean-command-to-clear-up-cmake-output) and reconfigure. or `cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang .`. Note that out-of-source builds are advised. Do `message(STATUS "CMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})` and check how it is set.  See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588855/how-do-you-set-cmake-c-compiler-and-cmake-cxx-compiler-for-building-assimp-for-i).

Comment: Remove cmake files delete CMakeCache.txt, cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILLER=clang .
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 7.0.1. But same error.

Comment: Then can you post the full output of `make VERBOSE=1` ? But did you set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` ?? You set only C_FLAGS_DEBUG, they won't affect normal builds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I forget to add options to the linker.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.11)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang)
project (Tutorial)


add_executable(Tutorial test_fuzzer.cc)
target_compile_options(Tutorial
            PRIVATE $<$<C_COMPILER_ID:Clang>:-g -O1 -fsanitize=fuzzer>
            )

target_link_libraries(Tutorial
            PRIVATE $<$<C_COMPILER_ID:Clang>:-fsanitize=fuzzer>
            )
```

Comment: hi,how long will a fuzz test run?

Comment: @tianyu LibFuzz will run until the first crash.