# CMake: `call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘_Tp std::accumulate`

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, c++20

In a CMake project I get the output:

```
[main] Building folder: cmake-test 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/jonathan/Projects/cmake-test/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 14
[build] Scanning dependencies of target hello_cmake
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hello_cmake.dir/main.cpp.o
[build] /home/jonathan/Projects/cmake-test/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
[build] /home/jonathan/Projects/cmake-test/main.cpp:25:43: error: ‘constexpr size_t pushConstantsSize(const std::array<std::variant<unsigned int, float>, NumPushConstants>&) [with long unsigned int NumPushConstants = 1; size_t = long unsigned int]’ called in a constant expression
[build]    25 |     constexpr size_t x = pushConstantsSize(pushConstants);
[build]       |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /home/jonathan/Projects/cmake-test/main.cpp:9:18: note: ‘constexpr size_t pushConstantsSize(const std::array<std::variant<unsigned int, float>, NumPushConstants>&) [with long unsigned int NumPushConstants = 1; size_t = long unsigned int]’ is not usable as a ‘constexpr’ function because:
[build]     9 | constexpr size_t pushConstantsSize(std::array<std::variant<uint32_t,float>,NumPushConstants> const& pushConstants) {
[build]       |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /home/jonathan/Projects/cmake-test/main.cpp:14:47: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘_Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation) [with _InputIterator = const std::variant<unsigned int, float>*; _Tp = long unsigned int; _BinaryOperation = pushConstantsSize(const std::array<std::variant<unsigned int, float>, NumPushConstants>&) [with long unsigned int NumPushConstants = 1; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(std::size_t, auto:23)>]’
[build]    14 |     return static_cast<size_t>(std::accumulate(pushConstants.cbegin(),pushConstants.cend(),
[build]       |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]    15 |         std::size_t{ 0 },
[build]       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                      
[build]    16 |         [size_fn](std::size_t acc, auto const var) { return acc + std::visit(size_fn,var); }
[build]       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]    17 |     ));
[build]       |     ~                                          
[build] make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello_cmake.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/hello_cmake.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/hello_cmake.dir/all] Error 2
[build] make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

The error as given by IntelliSense:

[image]

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <array> // std::array
#include <numeric> // std::accumulate
#include <variant> // std::variant
#include <stdint.h> // uint32_t
#include <iostream>

template <size_t NumPushConstants>
constexpr size_t pushConstantsSize(std::array<std::variant<uint32_t,float>,NumPushConstants> const& pushConstants) {
    auto size_fn = [](auto const& var) -> size_t {
        using T = std::decay_t<decltype(var)>;
        return sizeof(T);
    };
    return static_cast<size_t>(std::accumulate(pushConstants.cbegin(),pushConstants.cend(),
        std::size_t{ 0 },
        [size_fn](std::size_t acc, auto const var) { return acc + std::visit(size_fn,var); }
    ));
}

int main() {
    constexpr size_t num = 1;
    static std::array<std::variant<uint32_t,float>,num> const pushConstants = {
        uint32_t {  1 }
    };
    constexpr size_t x = pushConstantsSize(pushConstants);
    std::cout << "size:" << x <<std::endl;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project (hello_cmake)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

The minimal reproducible exmaple project zip: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b33hWUkLgQh8knvKV5k3_jDq1uJIUuTv/view?usp=sharing

When implementing the same code here https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/esPd87r4o, it works, this is not unexpected as this is likely an issue with CMake configuration.

For the `constexpr` implementation of [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) I am using CPP 20 and GCC 10.2.0, as is specified it requires under:

> `constexpr` for numeric algorithms

At: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

[image]

`CMakeLists.txt` includes `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)`

Looking at compilers installed on my systems:

```sh
jonathan@jonathan-MS-7B22:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

jonathan@jonathan-MS-7B22:~$ gcc-10 --version
gcc-10 (Ubuntu 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

jonathan@jonathan-MS-7B22:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

jonathan@jonathan-MS-7B22:~$ g++-10 --version
g++-10 (Ubuntu 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

jonathan@jonathan-MS-7B22:~$
```

CMake installed:

```sh
jonathan@jonathan-MS-7B22:~$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.16.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
jonathan@jonathan-MS-7B22:~$
```

I'm using the visual studio code [CMake Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) extension for ease, setup as such:

[image]

My best guess at the moment is some aspect is defaulting to using `gcc` over `gcc-10` which leads to this problem affecting the whole project, but I have no idea where this could be or how I might fix it.

I'm pretty much at a loss for what do to here, any help would be really appreciate, thank you for reading this far.

## Update

I believe I have found where the error originates from, on reconfiguring the project I get the output:

```
[main] Configuring folder: cmake-test 
[driver] Removing /home/jonathan/Projects/cmake-test/build/CMakeCache.txt
[driver] Removing /home/jonathan/Projects/cmake-test/build/CMakeFiles
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/bin/gcc-10 -H/home/jonathan/Projects/cmake-test -B/home/jonathan/Projects/cmake-test/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /bin/gcc-10
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /bin/gcc-10 -- works
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++ -- works
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /home/jonathan/Projects/cmake-test/build
```

The line of note being `The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0`, I think this is what ultimately causes the error, I need to set `The CXX compiler` to 10.2.0 instead. I'm not sure how to change this.

Comment: "so I think it's easiest to simply give the the .zip file" Uh, no. Please provide a [mcve]. Your build is also emitting a `compile_commands.json` so you can check to see in that file if the flags/compiler are set correctly there.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error here.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n3f5Mz1ah) I'm not very inclined to download and rummage through a zip file instead of getting the information from the question, so I don't know what differs between this and your actual code, but I've demonstrated GCC 10.2 successfully using `std::accumulate` in constant evaluation.

Comment: I would delete the CMake cache folder reconfigure it. There is a command built in vscode's CMake plugin to do that.

Comment: @Barry Updated to use minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @chris Updated to use minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I notice CMake 3.8 doesn't support `20` as a `CXX_STANDARD` value. I'm not sure if that's relevant since there's no mention of CMake giving a configuration error.

Comment: @chris Updated to `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)` seems to make no difference (sorry for double commenting this, had to change last one)

Comment: Try adding `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`.

Comment: @rustyx Doesn't seem to change anything, I've added an update to the bottom of the question, I think it highlights the problem (although I'm not certain).

Comment: When you click on "select a kit", do you see both C and CXX compilers detected for GCC 10, or only C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the update section note `The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0` to fix this you can do `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++-10")` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22619145/4301453) and reload the project.

This seems to work.

Although I'm not certain this is the best answer, it works for now.