# how to set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER for QMYSQL driver building

Tags: qt, cmake

I got this error below when I run the qt-cmake command guided by qt

```
D:\build-sqldrivers>D:\Qt\6.5.1\msvc2019_64\bin\qt-cmake -G Ninja D:\Qt\6.5.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\Qt\6.5.1\mariadb -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\include" -DMySQL_LIBRARY="C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\lib\libmariadb.lib"
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The ASM compiler identification is unknown
-- Didn't find assembler
```

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 and set C, C++ compiler on QT Creator kit>compiler
but I don't know how to set C++ compiler on the cmake command

D:\Qt\6.5.1\msvc2019_64\bin\qt-cmake -G Ninja D:\Qt\6.5.1\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\Qt\6.5.1\mariadb -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\include" -DMySQL_LIBRARY="C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\lib\libmariadb.lib"

I followed the guide as below on [this page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html#qmysql)

```
> mkdir build-sqldrivers 
> cd build-sqldrivers
> 
> qt-cmake -G Ninja
> <qt_installation_path>\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers
> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<qt_installation_path>\<platform> -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\mysql-8.0.22-winx64\include" -DMySQL_LIBRARY="C:\mysql-8.0.22-winx64\lib\libmysql.lib" 
> cmake --build . 
> cmake --install .
```

for sure I was Java programmer and I am new about building cmake stuff but at least I understand that it needs some argument to set cxx compiler
Please don't hesitate to get me a hint for running the command above without an error

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set CMAKE\_C\_COMPILER and CMAKE\_CXX\_COMPILER for building Assimp for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588855/how-do-you-set-cmake-c-compiler-and-cmake-cxx-compiler-for-building-assimp-for-i)

Comment: use the `CMAKE_X_COMPILER` flags where `X` is your language. ie `C`, `CXX` etc. `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/compiler ...`