# In CMake why is it okay to set the compiler without also setting the linker?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I'm newly learning CMake. In the course of my various readings, I sometimes encounter instruction to explicitly set the C/C++ compiler, e.g. by passing a `-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/path/to/compiler"` argument to `cmake`, or a `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/path/to/compiler")` statement in your CMakeLists.txt or a `"cacheVariables": {"CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "/path/to/compiler"}` line in your `CMakePresets.json`. (One example is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588855/how-do-you-set-cmake-c-compiler-and-cmake-cxx-compiler-for-building-assimp-for-i), but there are obviously many similar Q&A/tutorials with similar guidance). One use-case that comes to mind is on Windows, where I believe Visual Studio installs `cl.exe` by default and gives you the option to additionally install `clang-cl.exe`.

But doesn't your choice of compiler also drive your choice of other toolchain utilities, e.g. the linker, maybe the archiver, etc.? Why is it sufficient to only set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` but not some corresponding variable that controls the linker, e.g. `CMAKE_LINKER`?

What I mean is: I'm aware that there are CMake cache variables to control both the choice of compiler and linker, but *broadly speaking*, online tutorials, articles, Stack Overflow posts, etc., that discuss setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` do not also hand-in-hand discuss setting `CMAKE_LINKER`. E.g. if I explicitly do `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "gcc")`, why don't I need to also explicitly do `set(CMAKE_LINKER "ld")`?

Can someone please explain the relationship between the compiler and linker (and other related toolchain utilities) in the context of CMake? Why is it sufficient to only set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` but not some corresponding variable that controls the linker, e.g. `CMAKE_LINKER`?

---

(I have a not-fully-formed notion in my head that "compilers" like `gcc` and presumably `cl.exe` are actually "compiler *drivers*" which means that they actually wrap/encapsulate other executables that actually do the compiling and linking (and archiving?) -- is this correct, and related to the question?)

Comment: Your notion that what are commonly called "compilers" are in fact toolchain drivers. For example, in the case of GCC (the GNU compiler collection), the driver is `gcc` but the compiler is `cc1` and the linker is usually `ld`.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb - Your comment is sparking some connections from disparate learnings in my brain. I wonder if I might be able to nudge you into expanding your comment into an answer? :) I can't yet form a full mental model from these separate ideas: is `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` actually for choosing a toolchain driver/could the variable name have been more precise? Why offer a variable to choose a driver, but also a discrete linker? I.e. why offer both `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_LINKER`? It seems like you would want either 1) only a driver, or 2) discrete choices for compiler and linker.

Comment: An easy way is `man gcc` or `man clang`. Those pages lay it out pretty darn well.

Comment: Since you're new to learning CMake, I strongly recommend reading "Professional CMake" by Craig Scott. (No affiliation, it's just a good book.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By knowing a compiler, in most cases CMake is able to **guess** about location of other utilities needed for compile, link and some other processes.

The guessing is performed according to the compiler's path and information, which compiler is able to report about itself (see e.g. description of variable [CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_ID](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html)). As for the link process, by default CMake uses the compiler itself for drive the linking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25274328/3440745.

In rare cases, when CMake fails to guess about other parts of the toolchain, one need to additionally set other variables (which is normally done in a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling)).